# get text to display in real time on webpage

Tags: javascript, json, get

I am trying to get text to display real time below the textbox as soon as I click submit I used to JavaScript code below but it does not work.

Whenever I put the 'json' at the end the code is rendered useless, It's not calling.

it just don't work.

Is there any other way to do this.

```
$(function () {
        $.get('dash/xhrGetListings', function (o) {
            for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
                $('#listInserts').append('<p>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></p>');
            }
        }, 'json');
    })
```

Comment: You haven't close you function

Comment: yeah my mistake. thanks for that but still don't work

Comment: well open up your console (e.g. firebug or chrome dev tools) and check the error it returns. I believe it is the best way to debug js errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the getJSON method?

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('dash/xhrGetListings', function (o) {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            $('#listInserts').append('<p>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">X</a></p>');
        }
    });
});
```

If you aren't getting anything, check the browser's console and network panel to see if there is a problem either with your request (404, 500 server errors...) or with the data you're receiving (maybe `o` is not array-like, maybe there is no `text` or `id` properties).

Comment: thanks for that but still don't work firebug is saying it is some sort of html error table error or something.

Comment: Why don't you paste here that error, so we can help you?

Comment: I fixed it thanks guys it was a problem with the fetch.

Comment: it shows but I still have to refresh the page. now how do I enable real time?